# How could the window.rootViewController not be the initialViewController?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, interface-builder, uisplitviewcontroller

I'm trying to transform my existing iOS app to have a master detail view as the root view. I created a new Master Detail project in Xcode to serve as a template. However, despite having an identical **AppDelegate.swift** and nearly identical storyboard files, I'm encountering an exception resulting from the `window.rootViewController` not being the `initialViewController` defined in the storyboard.

From **Info.plist**:

```
<key>UIMainStoryboardFile</key>
<string>Main</string>
```

From **Main.storyboard**:

```
<document ... initialViewController="Z2E-r9-vU1">
  <!-- ... -->
  <!--SplitViewTitle-->
  <scene sceneID="dlH-f9-ql3">
    <objects>
      <splitViewController title="SplitViewTitle" id="Z2E-r9-vU1" sceneMemberID="viewController">
```

Exception occurs here in **AppDelegate.swift**:

```
@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, UISplitViewControllerDelegate {
  var window: UIWindow?
  func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    let splitViewController = self.window!.rootViewController as UISplitViewController
```

In the default Master Detail project created by Xcode, the `self.window!.rootViewController` will be the `UISplitViewController`, but in my app it will be a `UINavigationController`, specifically, the navigation controller for the master view.

**How could this be the case?** From my understanding of the `rootViewController`, it should be set to the `initialViewController` on launch. To quote some official [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/WindowAndScreenGuide/WindowScreenRolesinApp/WindowScreenRolesinApp.html):

> at launch time iOS:
>
> - Instantiates a window.
> - Loads the main storyboard and instantiates its initial view controller.
> - Assigns the new view controller to the window’s rootViewController property and then makes the window visible.

**Update:**

This is starting to look like a bug in Xcode. I've reproduced the exact exception merely by creating a new Master Detail project, setting the Deployment Target to 7.1 and running it on the iPhone 5 (7.1) simulator. It does work correctly on the iPhone 5 (8.1) simulator.

**Update 2:**
I had been using Xcode `Version 6.1 (6A1052c)`. I just upgraded to the latest version, `Version 6.1.1 (6A2008a)`, but it does not resolve this easily reproducible issue. I will file a bug report with Apple and move on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use SplitViewController for iPhone in iOS versions before 8.0 - only for iPads.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UISplitViewController_class/index.html

`In iOS 8 and later, you can use the UISplitViewController class on all iOS devices; in previous versions of iOS, the class is available only on iPad.`

Comment: Thanks, but my question is "why is it not the rootViewController?" given that I have set it as the initialViewController. I'd rather not have to make a programmatic fix for something that should be default behavior.

Comment: So when you check rootViewController in debug, it isn't SplitViewController class?

Comment: That is correct, at least for the iPhone 5 (7.1) case.

Comment: but you can't use SplitViewController for iPhone till iOS 8.0 - only for iPads. `In iOS 8 and later, you can use the UISplitViewController class on all iOS devices; in previous versions of iOS, the class is available only on iPad.`

Comment: I never saw that page - that's a great reference. If you want to post another answer with that answer and a link to that page, I would accept it. Thanks.